# Tombstone a usercontrol in wp7

Tags: user-controls, windows-phone-7.1, state, tombstone

I have created a roundtextbox usercontrol and using it on all pages.
While debugging for Tombstone , I see only a single line in place of round textbox.
I tried to save the state of textbox/Grid containing the textbox/Page but still the roundtextbox collapses to form a single line.
Here is my code for roundtextbox

```
<Viewbox Width="420" >
    <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="1"   BorderBrush="Black" >
        <TextBox Name="textbox" MaxLength="255" Margin="-8" Width="420"  FontFamily="../fonts/DroidSans.ttf#Droid Sans" AcceptsReturn="True"  TextWrapping="Wrap" IsReadOnly="False" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" >
        </TextBox>
    </Border>
</Viewbox>
```

Thanks and Regards,
Kanaya

Answer (score 0):

Got it,
For anyone who faces the same issue. REMOVE the font family from the textbox and it will work fine.
Thanks,
Kanaya